# Animations in angular material not working. Problem isn't NoopAnimationsModule or version of material or exports in app.module.ts

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material2

I am new to Angular 2 and I'm trying to implement angular material into my form. I have read previous questions on this subject on SO and none of the solutions helped me. 
it's not a problem of NoopAnimationsModule in my app.module.ts. And (I think) it's not a problem in version of angular material. I have also added theme in styles.scss. I would be grateful if you could have a quick look.
Thank you!

package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~8.0.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.4",
    "@ngmodule/material-carousel": "^0.5.1",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.38.1",
    "angular-mapbox": "^0.2.2",
    "angular-material": "^1.1.20",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "mapbox-gl": "^0.54.1",
    "ngx-mapbox-gl": "^4.3.0",
    "popper": "^1.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.800.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/mapbox-gl": "^0.51.12",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
    <p>
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Outline form field</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder">
    <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
    <mat-hint>Hint</mat-hint>
  </mat-form-field>
</p>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact-form',
  templateUrl: './contact-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-form.component.scss'],

})
export class ContactFormComponent implements OnInit {

  contactForm:FormGroup;



  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.contactForm = this.fb.group({

      username: '',
      email: '',
      phone:'',
      message:''
    })

    this.contactForm.valueChanges.subscribe()

  }

}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CreateProductComponent } from './pages/create-product/create-product.component';
import { ProductComponent } from './components/product/product.component';
import { NavBarComponent } from './components/nav-bar/nav-bar.component';
import { ProductPageComponent } from './pages/product-page/product-page.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';
import { MatCarouselModule } from '@ngmodule/material-carousel';
import { FaqComponent } from './pages/faq/faq.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MentionsLegalesComponent } from './mentions-legales/mentions-legales.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './pages/footer/footer.component';
import {A11yModule} from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import {PortalModule} from '@angular/cdk/portal';
import {CdkStepperModule} from '@angular/cdk/stepper';
import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table';
import {MatAutocompleteModule} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatButtonToggleModule} from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import {MatChipsModule} from '@angular/material/chips';
import {MatStepperModule} from '@angular/material/stepper';
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {MatDividerModule} from '@angular/material/divider';
import {MatExpansionModule} from '@angular/material/expansion';
import {MatGridListModule} from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';
import {MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';
import {MatNativeDateModule, MatRippleModule} from '@angular/material/core';
import {MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatProgressBarModule} from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import {MatRadioModule} from '@angular/material/radio';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import {MatSidenavModule} from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import {MatSliderModule} from '@angular/material/slider';
import {MatSlideToggleModule} from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import {MatSnackBarModule} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import {MatSortModule} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { ContactFormComponent } from './components/contact-form/contact-form.component';




@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CreateProductComponent,
    ProductComponent,
    NavBarComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    ProductPageComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    FaqComponent,
    MentionsLegalesComponent,
    ContactFormComponent

  ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatCarouselModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatExpansionModule, 
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
  ],

  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],

  exports: [
    A11yModule,
    CdkStepperModule,
    CdkTableModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    PortalModule,
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Does animation work without your custom theme?

Comment: I am using this theme > @import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css' and not a custom theme.

Comment: is it possible for you to create a stackblitz?

Comment: Not atm. What files you need I can edit my answer. Thank you

Comment: Why are you mixing incompatible versions of Angular and Angular CDK/Material? If you're using Angular v8, you should use Angular CDK/Material v8.

Answer (score 1):

I found it!

the problem was I added encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom in the component where I was importing my form. Thank you all for your answers and help.

Comment: Why does that ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom break the animation?

Comment: How did you resolve the issue without removing ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom?